# Pointing to an objects enum/tag to get a string,

Tags: objective-c

I need to get a buttons Enum to use in methods requiring the buttons name.

```
enum {
    Arle = 1,
    Bain, 
    ...   
};

arle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
arle.tag = Arle;
```

I can't point to arle.tag because its a double and not a string, is there anything I could point to, to get @"Arle" as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no way in C to convert an enum automatically to a string.

**Edit:**

You have to convert manually:

```
static inline NSString *enum2String(int value)
{
    switch(value) {
        case Arle: return @"Arle";
        case Bain: return @"Bain";
        default: return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not automatically but is there any way at all?